# Predict length and width of an object (NLP/Tabular Data)

Tags: nlp, regression, multi-output

I need to do a model that predict the dimensions (length and width) of an object, given some inputs. The input are not important for my question, but are not images.

Should I just do a double regression ? Can I use somehow the fact that I work only on a "half dimension", as I know (by definition) that length > width ?

For now I've got two ideas:

- to predict the length, and then the width (but I'm not sure it would be so usefull)
- to make a custom loss to adjust the prediction (e.g. if X=2,Y=3, predX=3, predY=2, the loss should be 0)

But I'm not sure any of them is good.

Comment: I would start by trying to understand the data as much as possible, plotting length vs. width, seeing how many unique values, taking histograms, etc.

Are your two dimensions independent, or dependent? In other words, is width a (possibly simple) function of length? Then it might make sense to predict width from length or even see if there's a better way to estimate.